# Styles not applied to SVG element in firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, svg

This is a weird problem. I have some simple HTML here.

```
<a href="#">
    <svg><use xlink:href="/images/iconSprite.svg#facebook"></use></svg>
</a>
```

and I am styling it like this.

```
A{width:40px; height:40px;}    

A > SVG{
    width: 65%;
    height: 65%;
    fill: white;
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and for some reason in IE9, however in Firefox (latest) and IE 10 and 11 the element dies not get styled at all.

However, if I change the selector from `A > SVG` to `A > *` it works perfectly in both cases. This seems hacky and I'd rather understand what the problem is and come up with a neater solution if possible.

I would have thought if it wasn't possible to use SVG in a selector then there would be lots of mentions of this on the internet but I couldn't find anything so I must be doing something wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by capitalizing the `svg` selector in CSS. Take the following code snippet for example, where using `SVG` does not work, but `svg` does.

## Example:

```css
.wrap-a > SVG {
    background: blue;
}
.wrap-b > svg {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap-a">
    <svg width="226" height="226"><circle cx="110" cy="107" r="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="red" /></svg>
</a>
<a class="wrap-b">
    <svg width="226" height="226"><circle cx="110" cy="107" r="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="red" /></svg>
</a>
```

This is most-likely related to SVG tags being case-sensitive, unlike HTML tags. The reason `*` works is because it is case-insensitive.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. The SVG element IS an HTML element and I always capitalize my HTML elements to differentiate them from classes. Stupid IE/Firefox. Thanks for the answer.